# How to manipulate a custom Spring Security UserDetails object?

Tags: spring-security

In a Spring Boot MVC application, a custom `UserDetails` implementation serves as `principal` and provides additional data for routine interaction with the user:

```java
public class ApplicationUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String displayName;
    private boolean hasSpecialPrivilege;

    //... mandatory overrides omitted
}
```

For testing purpose I build an endpoint which can change the properties like that:

```java
@GetMapping("/change")
public String setSpecialPrivilege(@AuthenticationPrincipal ApplicationUserDetails userDetails) {

    userDetails.setSpecialPrivilege(true);

    return "index";
}
```

The change lasts during the same request/response cycle, but at the next time the user calls the application, the initial values, which were set before adding the `UserDetails` object to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` are back in place. I tend to think that I have manipulated a proxy object which won't pass the change to its underlying object stored in the `SecurityContext`.

Is there a way to change the custom values of the `ApplicationUserDetails` without having to build and set a new `Authentication` instance?